# Android SlidingDrawer handle button not always opening the drawer on single tap

Tags: android, imageview, slidingdrawer

I have a slidingDrawer implemente in my layout and for the handle, I am using an ImageView.

Now everything works fine but sometimes ( more than often) when i click my handle image, it doesn't always opens (or closes) the drawer at once. I have to touch the handle multiple times to open/close it.

I have tried setting and testing with **android:focusable** and **android:focusableInTouchMode** as **false** for both the slidingDrawer as well as Button Image. This looks like that some focus of the parent is overriding the clild or something.

I have also tried replacing the Button Image with ImageView and still the same result.

Please help and let me know if I am missing something crucial here?

EDIT: Following is the snippet from my code

```
    <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:allowSingleTap="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:content="@+id/layout"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
    </ImageButton>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using it in a linearlayout? If you are, use framelayout

Comment: I am using frame layout itself .This is how my code looks like